# Pretty URL to custom joomla page

Tags: url, sef, .htaccess-configuration

I have an URL:

```
domain.com/photos?photoId=344
```

and I want to make pretty URL such as:

```
domain.com/photos/344
```

I tried to correct htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^photos/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) /photos?photoId=$1 [L]
```

But when clicking domain.com/photos/344 - i go to 404 error.

Maybe the error in Joomla SEF plugin? It's ON

Comment: Quick question: are your `photoId`s numbers only or may include letters as well?

Comment: @nyedidikeke Only numbers

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that (numbers only, from 0 to 9).

Comment: Hope your challenge is now resolved!

Comment: @nyedidikeke Sorry, but there is changes after correct. Maybe you have once more idea?

Comment: Can you please rephrase? I don't understand.

Comment: @nyedidikeke Maybe you have more ideas or experience how to make url pretty. Or maybe what can affect to htaccess rewrite?

Comment: @nyedidikeke I'm in panic. Link layout "photos?photoId=XXX" is awful

Comment: You should've wright your custom router.php for your component

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes you have *mod_rewrite* enabled.

You should go about this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# First, do redirect "/photos?photoId=something" to "/photos/something"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/photos\?photoId=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /photos/%1? [R=301,L]

# Then, internally rewrite "/photos/something" to "/photos?photoId=something"
RewriteRule ^photos/([0-9]+)$ /photos?photoId=$1 [L]
```

Comment: after this all links like domain.com/photos?photoId=something start to redirect to domain.com/photos/something, but go to 404 page =(

Comment: @user3774771: Can you elaborate further? Do you have other rules defined in your `.htaccess` file that possibly conflict with the above? It should actually work!

Comment: Here is my htaccess [link](http://pastebin.com/ZzqkxFqk). I changed regex for only numbers. But there is no result

Comment: Maybe RewriteCond with Query string can affect for it?